# Macros in python (PEP 638)

Tags: python, macros

A somewhat newer macro PEP in python is: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0638/. Using this, is it possible to define a macros such as the following:

```
PRINT = print ("Move from %s to %s." % (FROM, TO))
```

Or:

```
#define PRINT print ("Move from %s to %s." % (FROM, TO))
```

(or whatever the syntax is). If so, how could that be done?

Comment: The macro name has to end in `!`

Comment: See the section https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0638/#defining-macro-processors for how to define macros.

Comment: @Barmar what python version does that work in?

Comment: It's not clear that this has been implemented yet. It's just a proposal, only 7 months old.

Comment: @Barmar I see, so is there any macro module in pip or something for python, or currently it's not a thing and would need to roll your own cpp-ish thing.

Comment: It's not currently a thing, that's why he made this proposal. And if you read the discussion forums, there isn't concensus that it's needed.

Comment: I don't think it can be done as an add-on module, it requires changes to the Python parser itself.

Comment: @Barmar got it. I added a toy answer showing some basic text replacement as well.

Comment: If you're going to do it by in effect editing the file, you could use something like `m4`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very, very, very basic example of using a macro for basic zero-argument textual replacements. For anything more serious / non-trivial there are many other tools that can be used, such as [C's preprocessor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor):

```
# pypp.py

assert len(argv) == 3
# USAGE: $ python pypp.py script.py
# Does not allow arguments
# does not check whether it's in a string/comment.
# Very crude/basic, but but can be used for simple string-replacements
# such as the OP question.

from sys import argv
import re
with open(argv[-1], 'r') as f:
    program = f.read()
    matches = re.findall(r'\s*\#\s*define (\S+) (.+?)(?<!\\)\n', program)
    for match in matches:
        program = (program
                .replace(match[0], '###', 1) # ignore first occurrence (macro itself)
                .replace(match[0], match[1])
        )
    exec(program)
```